# How do I limit the size of the %TEMP% folder in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to limit the size of a user's %TEMP% folder under Windows 7? Our corporate systems have intentionally small hard drives, and some users have temp directories getting up to 1.5GB. It'd be helpful if we could limit that to, say half a GB. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use quotas? It will limit obviously everything in their homedirs but it works. You can also use a login script to empty the %temp% folders every time they log in.